# How can I hide DLL that loaded into the process memory?

Tags: windows, process

I performed "reflective DLL injection", but I am trying to determining if I can view the injected DLL? if so, how can I hide it?

Comment: Aside from technical feasibility, why would you want to?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish? There different methods with different shortcomings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in learning about reflective DLL injection.  The following page should cover what you need:

https://0x00sec.org/t/reflective-dll-injection/3080

You might expect that Security software, in particular, anti-exploit based software might be on the lookout for this and it is.  For example HitmanPro.

> Reflective DLL Injection
>
> Normally when you load a DLL in Windows, you call the API function LoadLibrary.
>   LoadLibrary takes the file path of a DLL as input and loads it into memory.
>   Reflective DLL loading refers to loading a DLL from memory rather than from disk.
>   Windows doesn’t have a LoadLibrary function that supports this, so to get this
>   functionality you have to write your own. One benefit to writing your own function is that
>   you can omit some of the things Windows normally does, such as registering the DLL
>   as a loaded module in the process, which makes the reflective loader sneakier when
>   being investigated. Meterpreter is an example of a tool that uses reflective loading to hide
>   itself. Mitigation is performed by analyzing if a DLL is reflectively loaded inside memory

https://www.sophos.com/en-us/medialibrary/Gated-Assets/white-papers/Sophos-Comprehensive-Exploit-Prevention-wpna.pdf

Comment: Did the Demonstration section of the linked article not help?